# How to get id in a jList if multiple column exists in single row in java swings Gui.?

Tags: java, database, swing

I am fetching data from database in `JList`, here I am using

```
   {
           ...
           ...

DefaultListModel m=new DefaultListModel();


String sqllist="select * from cnotezdetails cn where cn.case_count_no="+c+"";

System.out.println(sqllist);

pst=conn.prepareStatement(sqllist);

rs= pst.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    int id=rs.getInt(1);
    String date=rs.getString("nextDate");
    String status=rs.getString("status");
    String notes=rs.getString("notes");
    System.out.println(date);
    m.addElement(id+date+notes);
}
jList1.setModel(m);

}
tmp=(integer)JList1.getSelectedValue();
```

Here  I need to select only id value but it `getSelected` id, Date, notes. But I need to select only id value to comparing in database 
i.e.,

```
id     Date            notes

1      25/08/2014      note1

2      26/08/2014      note2
```

Here I need to fetch only the id value i.e., id=1,2,etc.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Wrap each row in a POJO (Plain Old Java Object), add this to your `JList` `ListModel`.  Use a `ListCellRenderer` to customise the way that the list data is rendered.  See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.  This way, you can "display" the data in any way you want, but still have access to other aspects as needed

Comment: is better, easier to use JTable (from structure posted) rather than JList, as hunting for index from shadowing classes painted in ListCellRenderer (is simple, possible without special effort, but required more than basic knowledges about Jave and Swing)

Comment: JTable with removed columns (JTable.removeColumn() remove column only from view value are/still are present in its model) and without JTableHeader looks like as JList

Comment: @mKorbel Agreed re `JTable`.  For displaying tabular data, as that clearly is, a `JTable` is the logical component to use.

Comment: I need use in jList and I have to fetch first column id in a full row.

Answer (score 1):

Just do like @MadProgrammer suggested. Use a simple POJO to wrapped the values. You can override the `toString()` to get your desired output. When the item is selected, just the get value from the pojo.

Something like:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class PojoListDemo {

    public PojoListDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(getPojoList()));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JList getPojoList() {
        JList list = new JList(getListModel());
        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    Pojo pojo = (Pojo) ((JList) e.getSource())
                            .getSelectedValue();
                    System.out.println("Selected id: " + pojo.getId());
                }
            }
        });
        return list;
    }

    private ListModel getListModel() {
        DefaultListModel<Pojo> model = new DefaultListModel<Pojo>();
        model.addElement(new Pojo(1, new Date(), "Hello World"));
        model.addElement(new Pojo(2, new Date(), "Hello Stack Overflow"));
        model.addElement(new Pojo(3, new Date(), "Hello Grandma"));
        return model;
    }

    class Pojo {
        private int id;
        private Date date;
        private String description;

        public Pojo(int id, Date date, String description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.date = date;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return MessageFormat.format("{0} - {1} - {2}", 
                    getId(), 
                    new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(getDate()),
                    getDescription());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new PojoListDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Creating the list from the db data is trivial, if you know how to use jdbc. Just add each result row attriubutes to the corresponding attributes in the pojo. Something like

```
private ListModel getListModel() {
    DefaultListModel<Pojo> model = new DefaultListModel<Pojo>();
    ...
    // access your database and get a ResultSet
    ...
    while(rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        Date date = rs.getDate("date");
        String description = rs.getString("description");
        model.addElement(new Pojo(id, date, description));
    }
    // close resources
    return model;
}
```

Comment: +1 for POJO with overridden `toString`.  No custom renderer necessary for trivial tasks like this.

Comment: Sir , I need to fetch data from database, also I have created swing Gui i.e., Jdialog Gui in that I have added list Jlist, in this JList I have to fetch data from database.

Comment: When you get your data, create a pojo from each row

Comment: Have you tested this code? Is this the basic functionality you are looking for, as far as display and getting the id from the selected item?

Comment: Yes, I have tested this code, It is working fine , but I need to fetch data from database.

Comment: I understand that. You seem to already know how to fetch data from the database, so I don't understand the problem. Do you understand the concept of wrapping your data in a pojo? Do you see my method `getPojoList()`? That is where I populate the `DefaultListModel`. You can do it in a similar way, except you will use your db data to populate each pojo object in your `while(rs.next()` loop

Comment: @ChandrashekaraYD Sorry, I meant in my `getListModel()` method. That's where I populate the model, not the `getPojoList()` method

Comment: @ChandrashekaraYD Take a look at my **Update**

Comment: String date=rs.getString("nextDate");
String status=rs.getString("status");
String notes=rs.getString("notes");
int id=rs.getInt(1);
System.out.println(date);

model.addElement(new Pojo(id,date,status));

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

Comment: That really doesn't tell me much. You need to make sure the pojo has the correct data types. Other than that, I have no idea what to do with that bit of code.

Comment: @ChandrashekaraYD please don't forget to accept (the check mark) the answer if it helped to solve your problem.

Comment: hai, My list is displaying like this,
1   Note1   25/06
2   NoteXYZ   26/06
..
..
100   Note1    25/06
I need to align the text in above given Pojo code
return MessageFormat.format("{0}  {1}  {2}", 
                    getId(), 
                    new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(getDate()),
                    getDescription());

Comment: Use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead of `MessageFormat` then

Comment: values containing both integers as well as strings , how can i use StringFormat?

Comment: Sorry but I can't hold you hand until you get everything the way you want it. String.format is something every Java developer should know. Google it, seach on SO or ask another question.